# How to update a dataframe column in pyspark based on another column value without using withColumn feature?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in which I am trying to update a column value.
To do this, we can simply use `spark.sql` and run an update query on the dataframe.

But is there a way we can use dataframe's native API to do the same ?
I was able to set values of a new column by first creating it with `withColumn` and then setting its value based on a condition.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("req_id", when(col("status") === "9088","Generated")
      .when(col("status") === "9089","Deactive")
      .otherwise("Unknown"))
```

But what if I already have a column `req_id` and it is with some values (not default values) where I want to update its value based on the column value `status`.
How can I update the value of the column `req_id` without doing a workaround like creating a new column and then updating its value ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.withColumn("req_id", ...)` actually adds or replaces (updates) the column `req_id` if it already exists. So I don't really understand your issue here.

Comment: I thought withColumn() is used only when you need a new column. Didn't know that you can apply that on an existing column as well. I'll try it and post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

As @blackbishop mentioned in his comment :

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("req_id", when(col("status") === "9088","Generated")
      .when(col("status") === "9089","Deactive")
      .otherwise("Unknown"))
```

Will either create the column `req_id` or replace the values inside it if the column already exist.