# How to create a Dataframe with update set similar to spark SQL in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to write the code below entirely in PySpark, as I plan to maintain  code integrity in PySpark instead of using Spark SQL.

```
df = spark.sql(f"update {fp} set status = 'success', date = now()")
```

Comment: Where's the data coming from for this dataframe? In general (e.g. some traditional sql database, csv, parquet) no, but if you're using delta tables it's possible to run update statements on them.

Comment: Hi @matkurek,data is from csv file, but internally we are loading the data into Dataframe  and transforming it.

Comment: Well, what is the exact error you get when you run this? And this is also "SparkSQL", so it's unclear what you mean by "integrity"

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I am not getting any error as such but I want to write my code exclusively in PySpark instead of using Spark SQL.

Comment: I don't know what that means. SparkSQL is a subset of Spark API, including Pyspark. They're not replacements of one another

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926900/how-to-update-a-dataframe-column-in-pyspark-based-on-another-column-value-withou